# Swift || Returning a class that can be used by other methods from an API call

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, completionhandler

I am making a call to HERE Weather API from a mobile App and need to return the current weather as an object so that other methods can use that information for a given time period (eg. 30 min update intervals).

I have a rough understanding of asynchronous calls based on this site https://fluffy.es/return-value-from-a-closure/ but I am still running into my problem where I can't access the Weather object I create outside of the closure of the completionHandler.

I have provided the Get method from my Weather class. I have also provided a call to that Get method in the AppDelegates file.

```
public static func Get(lat:String, long:String, completionHandler: @escaping (Weather?)  -> Void) {

    //Keys go here
    var request = URLRequest(
        url: URL(string: "https://weather.cit.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?app_code=-fJW5To2WdHdwQyYr_9ExQ&app_id=2m83HBDDcwAqTC2TqdLR&product=observation&latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+long+"&oneobservation=true")!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { dat, response, error in
        do {

            guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dat as! Data, options: []) else {throw JSONParseError.missingJSON}

            //parse json for dictionaries
            guard let response = json as? [String: Any] else {throw JSONParseError.responseNotADictionary}
            guard let observations = response["observations"] as? [String: Any] else {throw JSONParseError.observationsNotADictionary}
            guard let locationJSON = observations["location"] as? [Any] else {throw JSONParseError.locationNotAnArray}
            guard let location = locationJSON.first as? [String: Any] else {throw JSONParseError.locationNotADictionary}
            guard let observationJSON = location["observation"] as? [Any] else {throw JSONParseError.observationNotAnArray}
            guard let observation = observationJSON.first as? [String: Any] else {throw JSONParseError.observationNotADictionary}

            //search dictionaries for values
            guard let feedCreation = response["feedCreation"] as? String else {throw JSONParseError.missingFeedCreationObject}
            guard let city = location["city"] as? String else {throw JSONParseError.missingCityObject}
            guard let state = location["state"] as? String else {throw JSONParseError.missingStateObject}
            guard let temperature = observation["temperature"] as? String else {throw JSONParseError.missingTemperatureObject}
            guard let icon = observation["icon"] as? String else {throw JSONParseError.missingIconObject}
            guard let iconName = observation["iconName"] as? String else {throw JSONParseError.missingIconNameObject}

            //create weather object and return
            guard let currentWeather = Weather(feedCreation: feedCreation,state: state,city: city,temperature: temperature,icon: icon,iconName: iconName) else {throw WeatherObjectCreationError.objectCreationFailed}

            completionHandler(currentWeather)

        } catch {
            print("JSON Serialization error")
        }

    }).resume()
}
```

```
Weather.Get(lat:"32.9005", long:"-96.7869", completionHandler: {currentWeather in
            if let testWeather = currentWeather{
//Works fine
print(testWeather.city)
                print("completionHandler")
            }
})
//Error says testWeather is not intialized 
print(testWeather.city)
```

At the end of my Weather.Get call I should be able to access the testWeather object from other methods. Specifically, a method that modifies the speed limit based on the current weather in the area, which is returned by the Weather.Get call.

Comment: Yo've said what isn't happening but it would be helpful to know what is happening. Is it printing `"JSON Serialization error"` or `"completionHandler"`? If you put a breakpoint in the dataTask completion handler, does it ever get hit?

Comment: My apologies, when I print testWeather.city inside of the completionHandler everything prints. When I try to print outside of the completionHandler it says testWeather is not initialized. My understanding is that this is due to the order of how the code is executed (ie. print(testWeather.city) is executed before the completion handler is executed)

Comment: That is correct, you can only use `testWeather` within the closure but you can pass it to another method or save it to a variable so that other parts of your code can access it.

Comment: testWeather is local to the closure you are using. It cannot be accessed outside that closure. You have to save it any other weather object which can be accessed later like in a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have not understood is that the completion handler in your GET call is every bit as asynchronous as the original Weather API call. Thus you cannot run any code *after* it that depends on what's *in* it. The order of events is as follows:

```
// 1
Weather.Get(lat:"32.9005", long:"-96.7869", completionHandler: {currentWeather in
    if let testWeather = currentWeather{ // 3!!!
        print(testWeather.city) // 4!!!!!!
        print("completionHandler")
    }
})
print(testWeather.city) // 2
```

Moreover, what is the `testWeather` in the last line? Is it a property, `self.testWeather`? It would need to be. But even if it is, you have neglected to give `self.testWeather` a value; the `if let testWeather` is a *different* `testWeather` (it is local to the completion handler only and cannot "leak" out of it). However, even if you had done that, it *still* wouldn't work, because the code would *still* run in the wrong order:

```
// 1
Weather.Get(lat:"32.9005", long:"-96.7869", completionHandler: {currentWeather in
    if let testWeather = currentWeather{ // 3
        print(testWeather.city) // 4
        print("completionHandler") 
        self.testWeather = testWeather // 5; better but it won't help the _next_ print
    }
})
print(testWeather.city) // 2
```

Still, remembering to write to `self.testWeather` (5) would at least allow *other* code to access this value, provided it runs *later*.

Comment: This matter is thoroughly discussed in my blog post http://www.programmingios.net/you-cant-use-a-value-after-it-has-been-set-by-asyncronous-code/

Comment: Thank you, I understand the execution of the code better now. Does this mean that I should move any other calls that are dependent on the weather data inside of the Weather.Get comletionHandler?

Comment: In effect, absolutely, yes, if you want them to be called _in response_ to the fact that you now have the weather info. Again, see http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/.